# Thermostat two-wire: heat-only with R+Rh and O/B

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat, nest

**Updated Dec 1, 2022** (Previously I wrongly believed that the boiler is connected to a heat pump, whereas it is actually connected to a temperature sensor installed under the heat pump)

I want to replace a traditional thermostat by a new smart thermostat. I have Burham Alpine ALP150B boiler (for water radiators). The thermostat that controls it is wired using R+Rh (which are jumpered) and O/B. I expected it to have been wired using R and W instead.

[image]

The thermostat model is Honeywell RTH7600D1030. I consider installing Nest 3rd gen, which does support 2-wire heat-only installation with R+W but their online compatibility checker tool tells me that R+RC+O/B wires are not supported together.

I checked the wiring in the boiler, and I see no reason why the thermostat could not have been wired with R+W.

[image: boiler wiring]

[image: wiring manual page 1]
[image: wiring manual page 2]

The two wires labeled T-Stat in the diagram (which are at the top in the photo) go to the low-water cutoff and the thermostat in series.

[image: low water cutoff]

I am planning to install Nest 3rd gen thermostat. My primary question is:

1. Is it OK to wire the thermostat using R&W? Or is there a good reason why the R+Rh and O/B combination was used?

My secondary question is:

2. Is it OK to use Nest Power connector for the missing C-wire by using the white wire in the boiler that goes from the transformer (and into the blue wire nut that is on the right).

Comment: We'll definitely need as many photos of the wiring as we can to solve this mystery

Comment: What voltage is across the two thermostat conductors? And it's only two available conductors?

Comment: Brands and model #s of all the hardware, along with the pictures TPE asked for will be crucial in helping you resolve this. Odds are good there is a solution, we'll just need more info to avoid making random guesses.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I've updated the question.

Comment: @Matthew Yes, there are only two conductors. It is a 24V system (see the wiring diagram).